# Java Mail with attachment not working in smtp.office365.com, port: 587

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am not able to send email with attachment using  smtp.office365.com (without attachment its working), but with gmail its working.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

With the following configuration

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");        

props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols","TLSv1.2");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Comment: The error happens when connecting to the server, so I don't see how attachments or not would make a difference. I think you should **remove** the socket factory setting. You're using STARTTLS, which means the initial connection is **not** established with TLS. It is layered on the connection later, so trying to create the initial connection with a SSLSocketFactory is wrong, as that tries to establish TLS immediately. (The _"Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message"_ is usually a symptom of connecting to a plain non-TLS service.)

Comment: I am checking a condition if it is ssl then only setting socket factory

Comment: Office 365 uses STARTTLS, which means it starts unencrypted (no SSL/TLS). TLS is started by sending the STARTTLS command, and then JavaMail/JakartaMail takes care of it itself. This means you should not use a `SSLSocketFactory`. Or maybe you intended to set the property `mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory.class` instead (but setting it to `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` is unnecessary, as that is already the default)

Comment: I also recommend reading https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/SSLNOTES.txt